# Google SlidesApp: Duplicate a Google slide Shape and maintain "Shrink Text on overflow" property

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

Using Apps Script, I have to copy a group of shapes to another slide and adjust ratio.
This shape contains texts and these texts are not adjusted when the scale ratio is applied to the group.

When I created the original shape to duplicate (let say as a kind of template), I selected the Shrink Text on overflow option. This autofit property automatically adjusts text size.

Unfortunaly this property is not applied when I use the duplicate() in my script.
It seems that this autofit option is not available in apps script and I cannot apply this property to my duplicated group of shapes. Am I right ? Is it a bug ?

UPDATE:
To answer to Jason, here the piece of code I use to duplicate my group:

```
// In my 3rd slide, I define my box template (define all my shapes with
// the "Shrink text on overflow property I need then group everything)
var tileTemplate = presentation.getSlides()[2].getGroups()[0];

// inserGroup create a copy of the template in the destination slide
var newBox = slide.insertGroup(tileTemplate);

// The make customization, position, change of values ...
newBox.setLeft(<left value>);
newBox.setTop(<top value>);
...
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code to further check on your issue.

Comment: it looks like a bug to me, please fill new issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I included a sample code in my question. Do you think it is a bug or do I miss something ?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189153562